# UIScrollView bug? float foo = scrollview.zoomScale crashes the app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

In method viewForZoomingInScrollView: of the delegate to my scrollview I do the seemingly innocent:

// scrollView is the parameter passed to this method

float foo = scrollView.zoomScale

Boom! Crash, hello gdb.

Is this a known bug? Should I submit it?

Cheers,
Doug

Comment: What is your response of  NSLog("zoomScale: %f",scrollView.zoomScale);

Comment: you sure s crollview isnt nil?

Comment: A nil scrollview shouldn't crash, at least not at that point.

Comment: nil != scrollview Daniel. Besides Objective-C will happily allow you to do [thingThatIsNil zoomScale] without uttering a sound. Isn't that special ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get this and I thought it was because accessing zoomScale ends up calling viewForZoomingInScrollView, resulting in infinite recursion.

But I'm just speculating...

Comment: You're the winner moshy. For some inscrutable reason. scrollView.zoomScale involves a call to viewForZoomingInScrollView: so making the call within that methods recurses. In fact my debugger is currently trying to show me the output of 104684 stack frames. Oy. I'm thinkin' I'll keep my distance from this method.

Good lookin' out. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see the output in xcode's debugger console window.  Usually when you get a crash, there is some extra information available from the debugger console (open with command-shift-R, or Run > Console in the menu).  If there was an exception that caused the crash, it will say which one.  In any case, you can type `bt` (for backtrace) right after a crash and see the call stack when the crash occurs.

In your particular case, it's possible that you've accidentally released the `UIScrollView` object, but still have a pointer to where the old deallocated object was.  This would give you a crash on the next call to any method in `UIScrollView`, and since `zoomScale` is a getter accessor, it counts as a method call.  The most obvious symptom of this problem would be an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception in the debugger console when the crash occurs.

Comment: Tyler, I am sending a message to one of the parms passed to a ScrollViewDelegate method:

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

I successfully use various properties of scrollView such as scrollView.contentSize and scrollView.contentOffset I can work around this bug by observing changes to scrollView.contentSize and forming a ratio of: scrollView.contentSize/self.unzoomedContentSize.

This is not really a show stopper for me. It just worries me a bit about what other buggish bits are lying under rocks in the UIScrollView garden.

-Doug

Answer (score 1):

Doug thanks for that fix. Why didn't I think of that? >_<

And just as the OP said, grabbing the zoomScale property fires viewForZoomingInScrollView everytime.

Pretty much, don't use the zoomScale property inside **viewForZoomingInScrollView**,  if you do?  CRASH!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As moshy said, the reason the reason this happens is because the zoomScale property involves a call to viewForZoomingInScrollview, thus causing an infinite method call.