# Programmatically Scale selected UIView components on Zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that nests a `UIImage` and several symbols that are placed on the image programatically.

When the user zooms I need to scale these symbols up to have them keep the same size, whilst the underlying image is zoomed.

I placed the symbols and the image in a `UIView` to ensure the symbol position is alidned to image coordinates.

**First attempt:**

My attempt to do this is to place a routine in the `viewForZoomingInScrollview` method. But when reading the `myScrollView.zoomScale` parameter I hit the recursion problem that causes an infinte loop on `viewForZoomingInScrollview` (see stackoverflow [bug report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487531/uiscrollview-bug-float-foo-scrollview-zoomscale-crashes-the-app)).

I now struggle to find a way to determine the current zoomScale, hence am unable to determine the scale-factor that I need to apply when scaling my symbols.

Any hints how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following

a) have the zommable content attached to a UIView that sits below the UIScrollView
b) point `viewForZoomingInScrollView` to this  UIView
c) add non-zooming objects next to the UIView below the UIScrollView
d) add methods to recalculate the non-zomming-object-coordinates based on the zoomScale.

does it for me ...

Comment: What's the basic concept of recalculating positions? Could you give an example, please?